# How to test this properly? (C#, NUnit, Moq)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I hope this isn't too vague, but I'm just learning about unit testing with fakes using NUnit and Moq.  I understand the concepts and I am having no trouble writing tests for logical methods that perform a simple task, like manipulate some values or call a faked service.  But I'm scratching my head a bit trying to figure out how to test something like the following, which is a method that needs to do a data call and has several dependencies.

This is a class I have to authenticate users against a database:

```
class Authenticator: IAuthenticator
{

    private IConnectionHelper _connHelper;

    public Authenticator(IConnectionHelper connHelper)
    {
        _connHelper = connHelper;
    }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public UserModel User { get; private set; }

    public bool ValidateUser()
    {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId))
                return false;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
                return false;

            using (Entities db = new Entities(_connHelper))
            {
                MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
                byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.Password);
                byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
                string md5Hash = BitConverter.ToString(hash).ToUpper().Replace("-", string.Empty);

                var query = from u in db.Users
                            where u.UserId.ToUpper().Trim() == this.UserId.ToUpper()
                            where u.CPassword.Trim() == md5Hash
                            select u;

                this.User = query.FirstOrDefault();
            }



        if (this.User == null)
        {
            Log.LogLine(TraceLevel.Verbose, string.Format("Authentication failed for user '{0}'", this.UserId));
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.LogLine(TraceLevel.Verbose, string.Format("Successfully authenticated user '{0}'", this.UserId));
            return true;
        }
    }


}
```

I want to create a test fixture for this, but I'm unsure of how to handle it.

I can mock the IConnectionHelper, and test that the method will fail if the UserId or Password are null/empty,  but that's as far as I can get.  If IConnectionHelper is fake, then I obviously won't be able to test the database stuff, which I'm not sure I'm supposed to do anyway.   Can someone please shed some light on best practices here?

**EDIT**

The accepted answer from StuartLc definitely got me going in the right direction. I did have to do a little extra setup work for Entity Framework, basically using this as a reference:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx

Comment: You will need to abstract away an interface for db, so that it can be mocked.

Comment: @RyanGates Do you mean abstract the EF DbContext (Entities)?  Or do you mean create another service that I pass the user/pw to which handles the db interaction?  At some point won't I still be at a place where I need to test my query?

Comment: I would argue that testing your query and the programming logic are two different tests. Whenever I write unit tests, I prefer to not be dependent upon the database. This is how I do it, but far from the only way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Ryan's comment, your code is too tightly coupled to the dependencies `Entities` and `Log` to be easy to unit test (without having to resort to `Moles` or `Fakes`).

As a general rule, use of `new` to create any substantial dependency, or use of `static` methods like `Log` are generally the culprits preventing isolated unit testing with frameworks like `Moq`.

What I would suggest is refactoring the code as follows:

1. Separate out the concern of creation of the `Entities` class (presumably an ORM artifact like an EF `DbSet` or a Linq `DataContext`) into a factory, via an interface.
2. The `IConnectionHelper` dependency can be moved into the factory.
3. The static logger should also be stripped into an interface, and an instance should also be injected into your `Authenticator` and its lifespan also managed by your IoC container. The `Logger` and `EntitiesFactory` can both be injected

You should wind up with something like the below:

```
  public interface IEntitiesFactory
  {
     Entities Create();
  }

  public interface ILog
  {
     void LogLine(TraceLevel level, string message);
  }

  class Authenticator : IAuthenticator
  {
     private readonly IEntitiesFactory _entitiesFactory;
     private readonly ILog _log;

     public Authenticator(IEntitiesFactory entitiesFactory, ILog log)
     {
        _entitiesFactory = entitiesFactory;
        _log = log;
     }

     public string UserId { get; set; }
     public string Password { get; set; }
     public UserModel User { get; private set; }

     public bool ValidateUser()
     {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId))
           return false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
           return false;

        using (var db = _entitiesFactory.Create())
        {
           MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
           byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.Password);
           byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
           string md5Hash = BitConverter.ToString(hash).ToUpper().Replace("-", string.Empty);

           var query = from u in db.Users
                       where u.UserId.ToUpper().Trim() == this.UserId.ToUpper()
                       where u.CPassword.Trim() == md5Hash
                       select u;

           this.User = query.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        if (this.User == null)
        {
           _log.LogLine(TraceLevel.Verbose, string.Format("Authentication failed for user '{0}'", this.UserId));
           return false;
        }
        else
        {
           _log.LogLine(TraceLevel.Verbose, string.Format("Successfully authenticated user '{0}'", this.UserId));
           return true;
        }
     }
```

, where you can now `Mock` out the Entities Factory and the logger, and now provide fake `Users` data for the found / not found scenarios, and verify that the right stuff was sent to `logger`, etc, viz

```
 [Test]
 public void SomeTest()
 {
    var mockFactory = new Mock<IEntitiesFactory>();
    var mockEntities = new Mock<Entities>();
    var fakeUsers = new List<UserModel>
       {
          new UserModel
             {
                UserId = "Bob",
                CPassword = "TheHashOfSecret"
             }
       };
    mockEntities.SetupGet(_ => _.Users).Returns(fakeUsers.AsQueryable());
    mockFactory.Setup(_ => _.Create()).Returns(mockEntities.Object);
    var mockLog = new Mock<ILog>();
    var sut = new Authenticator(mockFactory.Object, mockLog.Object)
       {
          UserId = "Bob",
          Password = "Secret"
       };
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => sut.ValidateUser());
    Assert.IsNotNull(sut.User);
    mockLog.Verify(_ => _.LogLine(), Times.Once); ...
 }
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense, and I really appreciate you taking the time to provide such a detailed response!